# Can I have the Azure CLI and Google Cloud CLI on the same box?

Tags: azure, google-app-engine

I try to install Azure CLI after having the Google Cloud CLI installed. Here is what I get after running a azure-cli installation command.

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install azure-cli
Ign:1 http://packages.linuxmint.com sonya InRelease
Ign:2 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-sonya InRelease          

Hit:3 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease              

Hit:4 http://packages.linuxmint.com sonya Release                              

Hit:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     

Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                        

Ign:7 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-sonya Release             

Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cwchien/gradle/ubuntu xenial InRelease          

Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]     
Hit:10 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease         
....
```

It seems that it shares some files used by Google Cloud CLI. Can they be in the same box together? If yes, how to make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can always install the Google Cloud SDK manually from [the generic Linux package](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/#linux) (instead of the one pre-packaged for Ubuntu), in the location of your choice - so that it doesn't overlap/interfere with other SDKs. You just need to pay attention when executing and/or when hooking it up into your execution environment.